# Andare "in maniera ordinata" o "con ordine"?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, phrases

Quale variante è più usata in Italia:

Andare **in maniera ordinata**

Oppure

Andare **con ordine**

Es.:
1. Adesso racconto la storia. Non vi spaventate vado **in maniera ordinata**.

2. Adesso racconto la storia. Non vi spaventate vado **con ordine**.

Comment: In quale contesto?

Comment: Già che ci siamo, fra “Non vi spaventate” e “vado” ci va qualcosa (punto e virgola, due punti...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entrambe sembrano ugualmente corrette. La prima pare più formale, e dunque meno usata nella lingua parlata. In genere, la forma "in maniera + aggettivo" (complemento di modo direi) sembra più formale se usata al posto di un avverbio ("ordinatamente") o di altre formulazioni dello stesso complemento ("con ordine", come nel tuo caso).

Una versione (che a me pare) ben più comune delle due da te riportate è "andare per ordine". Tieni conto che nella lingua parlata ci sono grosse influenze dovute ai dialetti, quindi può darsi che questa mia impressione possa essere dovuta alla mia provenienza.

Answer (score 1):

Io preferirsco la seconda, mi sembra più immediata e coincisa per tale situazione contestuale. Magari, scorri alcumi esempi da questo sito: [esempi uso e traduzione "in maniera ordinata"](http://idiommaster.com/search/it-en?search-term=in%20maniera%20ordinata), [esempi uso "vado con ordine"](http://idiommaster.com/search/it-en?search-term=vado%20con%20ordine), ti possono essere d'aiuto a scegliere in base a certe affinità.